# How to use @reboot in /etc/cron.d

Tags: linux, cron

I am migrating individual user's crontabs to /etc/cron.d, as that would allow proper backup, restore and versioning.

So far, as I understand the only difference between user's crontabs and the etc ones is that you have to specify the user as the 6th column. **Is this right?**

And my main question, for which I couldn't find the answer anywhere on the internet:
What is the right way to use `@reboot` in /etc/cron.d or /etc/crontab?

something like 
`@reboot root command`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From [the crontab man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab):

> **Jobs in /etc/cron.d/**
>
> The jobs in cron.d are system jobs, which are used usually for more than one user. That's the reason why is name of the user needed. MAILTO on the first line is optional.
>
> **EXAMPLE FOR JOB IN /etc/cron.d/job**

```
 #login as root
 #create job with preferred editor (e.g. vim)
 MAILTO=root
 * * * * * root touch /tmp/file
```

That's the whole section about crontab in */etc*, so I guess the inclusion of the user under whose name the job runs is indeed the *only* difference.

Again from the same man page:

> These special time specification "nicknames" are supported, which replace the 5 initial time and date fields, and are prefixed by the '@' character:
>
> @reboot    :    Run once after reboot.

Thus your inference that the proper way to use *@reboot* is

```
   @reboot user_name command
```

is **correct**.

Answer (score 5):

If you're running it interactively as below, you don't specify the user:

```
crontab -e
@reboot /root/mycommand
```

If you're putting it as a file in /etc/cron.d, e.g. /etc/cron.d/mycronfile, you need to put the user:

```
@reboot root /root/mycommand
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of `/etc/crontab` you just have to add these lines.
`@reboot        command`

Where command can be any script or a single file.

Comment: Does that work?  `/etc/crontab` usually requires a user name.

Comment: @mwfearnley yes, it looks like a username is needed in the /etc/crontab file, even with reboot. Without "root" I got in "service cron status" the following message "Apr 20 17:59:11 movefiles cron[998]: Error: bad username; while reading /etc/crontab". After I changed the line to "@reboot root date >> ~/date.txt" it worked.