# Start tcpdump with script on system start

Tags: bash, cron, centos-7, centos-6, tcpdump

I'm trying to run a script on startup that runs the tcpdump command on Centos 7 and Centos 6.
The aim is to start a rolling pcap when the system starts.
I've tried using a cron with @reboot, but it doesn't seem to work.

I've tried running the tcpdump command directly from the cron with

`@reboot root tcpdump [-options]` and this works

I've tried running a script with a cron using

`@reboot root /path/to/script` and this did not work for starting the trace with the tcpdump command, although when I changed the script to create a file instead (to verify the script was getting called) this worked, so the script is running but the rolling pcap I'm trying to run isn't running.

I've tried running the script with nohup and setsid commands

`@reboot root nohup /path/to/script >/dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null &`

`@reboot root setsid /path/to/script >/dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null &`

neither worked, and just running the script normally from crontab and using nohup and setsid to run the tcpdump command in the script.

I also tried modifying the bash script to make sure the network interfaces were up before the tcpdump command was getting executed to make sure that wasn't the issue.

As far as i can tell there's no reason I shouldn't be able to execute the command in a script via cron, but nothing I've tried has worked so far. It doesn't need to be done via cron (I added a cron file to /etc/cron.d/ ) but it seemed like a good approach as the arguments to the command may be changed by a program so I'd like to keep it in its own file out of the way.

Comment: I see you used `@reboot root /path/to/script` and it worked as expected, but I don't see if you tried `@reboot root tcpdump [options..]`. ([Jobs in /etc/cron.d must specify the user as whom the job will run.](https://superuser.com/questions/708149/how-to-use-reboot-in-etc-cron-d))

Comment: @gnubeard sorry, that's what the first thing should've been (I've edited the question to correct). I did try calling the tcpdump command directly from the cron as root and this worked. Ideally I need the cron to call a script which calls the tcpdump command, which is what doesn't seem to work. I also cleared up the running the script part, I could run the script with the cron (verified by creating a file), but not to start the tcpdump